# ValueError: Unknown loss function:triplet_loss

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Getting below error while trying to convert the model into tflite or .pb file:

> ValueError: Unknown loss function:triplet_loss

I have checked different solutions posted in StackOverflow and GitHub but none of them worked for my code.

```
#calculates triplet loss
def triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, alpha = 0.2):

    anchor, positive, negative = y_pred[0], y_pred[1], y_pred[2]

    # triplet loss formula 
    pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)) )
    neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)) )
    basic_loss = pos_dist - neg_dist + alpha
    loss = tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0)
    return loss

# load the model    
model = load_model('facenet_model/model.h5', custom_objects={'triplet_loss': triplet_loss})
```

I believe I have to make some changes in the triplet loss function to resolve value error.

Answer (score 0):

Use axis parameter of tf.reduce_sum() equals to -1 for first two steps. This may solve your problem.

```
pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor,positive)),axis=-1)
neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor,negative)),axis=-1)
basic_loss = pos_dist - neg_dist + alpha
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.maximum(basic_loss,0.0))
```